# Prove: if A is a transformation matrix of orthonormal bases then A is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonal-matrices

I'm stuck proving this statement, perhaps because too many indexes are involved.
$A \in M \tiny nxn$ (F) Prove that if there exist B', B orthonormal bases of $F^n$, such that A is a transformation matrix from B' to B, then A is unitary.

I was trying to calculate what is the i,j-th cell of A, then to calculate the i,j-th cell of A*, and then show AA* = I, but I can't keep up with this many indexes.

Thanks in advance,
Barak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to verify that $||A(x)||=||x||$ for all $x$. It is also possible to express $\langle x, y \rangle$ in terms of  norms: $\langle x, y \rangle =\frac {||x+y||^{2}+||x-y||^{2}} 2$. This gives $\langle Ax, Ay \rangle =\langle x, y \rangle$ for all $x,y$. Hence $\langle A^{*}Ax, y \rangle = \langle Ax, Ay \rangle =\langle x, y \rangle$ which gives $A^{*}A=I$. Hence $AA^{*}=I$ too and $A$ is unitary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I'm sure I fully understand the meaning of ||A(x)||, what inner-product are you using there? And I can't understand where you used the orthonormal bases given in the question.

Comment: In the very first step I use the fact that $A$ maps one orthonormal basis to another. When you talk of orthonormal basis you are talking of orthogonal vectors which means you have an inner product (or dot product)  already given to you, right?.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, the inner-product is the standard one. However Its from F^n to F.. Did you use tr(AB*) as your inner product? Why is it ok to do this? Is it because B and B' are of the same dimension, thus there exists an isomorphism? Or am I missing the point entirely?

Comment: I did not use any inner product for $A$ and $A^{*}$. I have only used inner product of $Ax$, $Ay$ etc which are in $F^{n}$.

Comment: I got it, thanks. 

By the way, if I didnt know how to express $\langle x, y \rangle$ in the way you did, would I have to solve it using trasformations matrices?

Comment: No. Just start with the right side,  expand $||x+y||^{2}||$ as $||x||^{2}+||y||^{2} +2 \langle x , y \rangle $ and $||x-y||^{2}$ in a similar way and simplify the right hand side. You will get $\langle x , y \rangle $

Comment: Got it, thanks alot!